# Asus P8Z68 Deluxe Memory Disappeared

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

There was a time when they where working(16 Gigs-4 x 4GB dual chips which is on the vendors list), but now only 8GBs are seen by Windows 7 Ulti/64bit.
I have just reinstalled everything, Windows, the drivers and restored all settings to default yet nothing has changed.

There is nothing wrong with the RAM chips. They are all working; I know this because I've swapped and changed memory sticks and all of them are working.

My CPU, i7 2600k, is working fine with the correct voltage and I have tried most of the logical steps on recovering this but have fail'd.

System Specs:

H80 water cool
i7 2600k
4 x 4Gig DDR3
120 ssd
Asus P8Z68 Deluxe M/B
Nvidia GTX 580 3 Gig

Please help if you can

Comment: Does the BIOS show all 16GB when installed? Have you tested each slot individually (using a single stick of RAM)?  Are all 4 sots working?

Comment: all the slots are working. all the ram chips are working. in asus utility it shows that it recognizes there is ram in the slots. Bios only shows 8 Gigs of the 16 installed

Comment: Have you tried resetting your BIOS to default settings?  Have you enabled XMP by any chance (see BIOS->AI Overclock Tuner)?

Comment: i did that, nothing has changed?

Comment: still no idea guys?

Comment: ok so i have tested all the slots with a single 4 gig chip and they all are working

Comment: ive done this 16 times and all 16 times they are seen by bios\